# InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found. When working with Python Web scraper

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I am rather new to Web Scraping I have scrapped one of the zip files seen [here](https://www.omie.es/en/file-access-list?parents%5B0%5D=/&parents%5B1%5D=Day-ahead%20Market&parents%5B2%5D=1.%20Prices&dir=%20Day-ahead%20market%20hourly%20prices%20in%20Spain&realdir=marginalpdbc). The goal is to append them into a final data frame called final_df. Below is a snip of my code that runs well.

```
zip_url = "https://www.omie.es/es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_2017.zip"

dfs = []

with ZipFile(BytesIO(requests.get(zip_url, verify=False).content)) as zf:
    for file in zf.namelist():
        df = pd.read_csv(
            zf.open(file),
            sep=";",
            skiprows=1,
            skipfooter=1,
            engine="python",
            header=None,
        )
        dfs.append(df)
               

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)

# print first 10 rows:
print(final_df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

This works well for one year of zip files such as 2017 however I am curious if we could get it all in one swoop. My thinking is to create a F string and change the year in each iteration.

```
date_list = ['2017','2018','2019','2020','2021']
dfs = []
for dates in date_list:
    with ZipFile(BytesIO(requests.get(f'"https://www.omie.es/es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_{dates}.zip"', verify=False).content)) as zf:
        for file in zf.namelist():
            df = pd.read_csv(
                zf.open(file),
                sep=";",
                skiprows=1,
                skipfooter=1,
                engine="python",
                header=None,
                )
            dfs.append(df)



final_df = pd.concat(dfs)

# print first 10 rows:
print(final_df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

If we just isolate the f string we will see an output such as

"https://www.omie.es/es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_2020.zip"
"https://www.omie.es/es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_2021.zip"

...etc.

Yet when I feed this using the above loop I get an error saying "InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '"https://www.omie.es/es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_2017.zip"'"

What would be the best workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that `requests` module cannot identify what sort of protocol your requests needs (e.g. http, https, ftp etc.)

This happens in your case because you have a leading `"` character in your url:

```
with ZipFile(BytesIO(requests.get(f'"https://www.omie.es/es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_{dates}.zip"', verify=False).content)) as zf:
#                                 ^^^
```

Requests is looking for an adapter for `"https` protocol which doesn't exist :)

Just delete the extra quotes.